# confusion in sdo_relate anyintersect of Oracle 11g spatial database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, spatial, intersect

I run the following querys in oracle 11g :

1) `select a1.apid from access_point a1 where sdo_relate(a1.shape,a1.shape,'mask=equal') = 'TRUE' and a1.apid = 'a5vhe';`

2) `select a1.apid from access_point a1 where sdo_relate(a1.shape,a1.shape,'mask=anyintersect') = 'TRUE' and a1.apid = 'a5vhe';`

now oracle 11g documentation defines mask 'anyintersect' as "ANYINTERACT: Returns TRUE if the objects are not disjoint." Then why oracle returns record a1 for my Query 1 and returns none for QUERY2 ??

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo.

- Incorrect: `sdo_relate(a1.shape,a1.shape,'mask=anyintersect')`
- Correct: `sdo_relate(a1.shape,a1.shape,'mask=anyinteract')`